# How to check if the latest downloaded file is having the current time and date?

Tags: ipaf, paceautomationframework

How to check if the latest downloaded file is having the current time and date using Pace Automation Framework ?

Answer (score 0):

Sample code :

Use a custom tag :

#Tag=getLastModifiedFile, Att1=path, Att2=keyName

getLastModifiedFile=com.tr.execution.activities.GetLastModifiedFile

```
<activities>
    <activity id="ticket">
        
        <getLastModifiedFile path="./sample_xml" keyName="file"></getLastModifiedFile>
        <variable keyName="download_file" expression="var x ='${file}'.split('_'); x[5];" ></variable>
        <variable keyName="date" expression="var x ='${download_file}'.split('T'); x[0];" ></variable>
        <variable keyName="time" expression="var x ='${download_file}'.split('T'); x[1];" ></variable>
        <variable keyName="input_date_time" value="${date}${time}" ></variable>
        <date timezone="UTC" keyName="output_date_time" format="yyyyMMddhhmm"></date>
        <validation valGroupIds="Check_Date"></validation>
        
  </activity>
    
    <valGroup groupId="Check_Date">
        <validate variable="input_date_time" condition="equals" value="${output_date_time}" passMsg="PASSED" failMsg="FAILED" desc="VALIDATE TAG" expResult="VALIDATE the validation" >
        </validate>
    </valGroup>

</activities>
```